# ternary plot of ggtern not working in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity, ggtern

I want to use the output of `ggtern()` in a shiny app. However it seems to fail due to some constraints.

This is what it should look like:
 [image: What is should look like]

This is the actual shiny output:
[image: The output in shiny]

See here for a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggtern)

ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("ggtern")
        )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$ggtern <- renderPlot({
        ggtern(data.frame(x=10, y=30, z=60), aes(x, y, z)) + geom_point()
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do I overlook something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

place the plot function within a `print` command:

```
 output$ggtern <- renderPlot({
        print(ggtern(data.frame(x=10, y=30, z=60), aes(x, y, z)) + geom_point())
    })
```